# Is this the correct use of staticmethods?

Tags: python, inheritance, static-methods

Suppose I have two classes `A` and `B`, where `B` inherits from `A`. `A` and `B` both have a `bar` method. `A` has a `foo` method which is inherited by `B`.

I now want `bar` from `A` to be called whenever `foo` is called, irrespective of whether an object is an instance of `B` or `A`.

I googled and found that I should probably use `@staticmethod`. Is something like this correct? Or is it bad programming or some kind of logic error?

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()
        A.bar_static()
        
    def bar(self):
        print('Iam A')

    @staticmethod
    def bar_static():
        print('Iam A')

class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        print('Iam B')

    @staticmethod
    def bar_static():
        print('Iam B')
```

Output (this is what I want):

```
b = B()
b.foo()

Iam B
Iam A
```

Edit:
A possible Application is to compute a (thermodynamic) property, via a `prop` function. `prop` needs to call `prop_aux` to compute stuff. `prop` and `prop_aux` are  implemented by both, `A` and `B`, which are different models (`B` is an extension of `A` and therefore inherits from `A`). Now, the `B` implementation of `prop` calls the `B` implementation of `prop_aux`. However, since it's only extending the existing `A` model, it also calls the `A` implementation of `prop` (via `super()`). To compute stuff, the `A` implementation of `prop` calls `prop_aux`. When this happens, the `A` implementation of `prop` shall call the `A` implementation of `prop_aux` and not the `B` implementation of `prop_aux` (which would happen the self object is of class `B`.

Comment: I can't tell from the info you provided whether it makes sense or not. Can you provide more info on the actual application of this?

Comment: I have the feeling that this has nothing to do with static methods. You might as well use `A.bar(self)` in `A.foo`.

Comment: If `A.foo` is always supposed to call `A.bar`, then it should probably be a private method that `B` cannot/should not override.

Comment: `I now want bar from A to be called whenever foo is called` how is staticmethod related to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use `staticmethod` here. I will say, this seems like code smell in the design of your class.

And like most applications of `staticmethod`, just defining and using a regular function would suffice and probably be easier to understand:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()
        _bar_a()
        
def _bar_a(self):
    print('Iam A')


class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        _bar_b()

    
def _bar_b():
    print('Iam B')
```

Answer (score 0):

> now want bar from A to be called whenever foo is called

Call the function, pass the instance of the class `self`.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()   # outputs I am B
        A.bar(self)  # outputs I am A
        
    def bar(self):
        print('I am A')

class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        print('I am B')
        
b = B()
b.foo()
```